# Doubts in demonstrating Tarski's fixed-point theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, fixed-points

The book I'm using enunciates:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let X be set and $\sigma:P(X) \to P(X)$ increasing function $(x_1 \subset x_2 \subset X \Rightarrow \sigma(x_1) \subset \sigma(x_2) \subset X)$ then $\sigma$ has fixed point.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Consider $\tau= \{ x_1 \in P(X): x_1 \subset \sigma(x_1) \} \subset P(X)$ and take $x_0 := \bigcup \tau = \bigcup \{ x_1 \in P(X): x_1 \subset \sigma(x_1) \} $ then $\sigma(x_0)=x_0$.

I can not showed $\sigma(x_0)=x_0$.

Comment: Your definition of $\tau$ is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, i already edited.

Comment: Can you show that $x_0\subseteq\sigma(x_0)$?

Comment: take $y \in x_0 = \bigcup \tau$ then $\exists A \in \tau $ such that $y \in A$, so $A \in P(X) $ such that $ A \subset \sigma(A)$. Therefore $y \in A \subset \sigma(A) \subset \sigma(x_0)$. right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Can you prove that $\sigma(x_0)\subseteq\sigma(\sigma(x_0))$?

Comment: Just use that $\sigma$ is increasing.

Comment: Yes. So can you conclude that $\sigma(x_0)\in\tau$?

Comment: $\sigma(x_0)$ satisfies the properties of $\tau$. Take $y \in \sigma(x_0)$ with $\sigma(x_0) \in \tau$ then $y \in \bigcup \tau = x_0$,so $\sigma(x_0)=x_0$.

Comment: So, it seems you can show that $\sigma(x_0)=x_0$ now.